# Trabajar vs militar

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los verbos militar y trabajar? Escucho el uso del primero en varios contextos en donde cabe el segundo, como “por entonces ella militaba en una casa de cuido”. ¿Cuando se dice uno y cuando el otro?

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Militar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PFlXEFf)* es un concepto bastante específico, que a veces se superpone con *trabajar*, pero no siempre. El ejemplo que das suena como una expresión idiomática o un uso dialectal.

El verbo *militar* se refiere generalmente a ser miembro activo de una facción política. Una persona que milita para un partido puede también trabajar para el mismo (en el sentido de ser un empleado de la organización partidaria), pero una cosa no implica la otra.

Nunca había escuchado *militar* usado como sinónimo de *trabajar* en el contexto de tu ejemplo (trabajar en una institución que no tiene relación con la política o el activismo de ninguna clase). No estoy diciendo que sea incorrecto, pero sí que probablemente está restringido a ciertas regiones. (Este significado no figura en el DLE ni en el Diccionario de Americanismos.)

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración! Escuche la frase del ejemplo en un podcast de Radio Ambulante. La historia tomó lugar en Puerto Rico, así q queda posible que el uso es particular de allá.

Comment: @Forest - ¿Cuál episodio?  Radio Ambulante ha publicado el texto del audio para cada episodio.  Sin embargo, no logro encontrar esa frase.  ¿Nos podrías ayudar a encontrar esa sección?

Comment: El episodio se llama “El Conteo”. Así se describió una de las personas principales - ella cuya abuela murió después de la tormenta (Francesca si no me equivoco). Por lo menos eso es lo que escuché porque de una lo anoté como algo para investigar luego. Espero que no me equivoqué...

Comment: Escuché ese episodio hace varias semanas.  Hoy eché un ojo hoy a la transcripción, y no logro encontrar la parte que estás recordando.  Puede que la transcriptión no sea exactamente fiel al audio.  Luis es el narrador y Francheska, Miosotis y Glorimar cuentan su experiencias. ¿Te acuerdas cuál dijo la frase que anotaste?

Comment: No estoy 100% cierto pero pienso que fuera Luis, el narrador. Tendría que volver al episodio para averiguar pero para ser honesto, no quiero invertir tanto tiempo escuchándolo de nuevo. :-) Bien puede ser que yo me equivoqué. Lo interesante para mi es que sin embargo aprendí algo nuevo en hacer la pregunta.